# Python - Tkinter pre-selected button

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I have a little script in python which is creating a windows popup using tkinter. 
Some text to fill and after, two buttons : Dismiss / OK.

I would like to allow the user just to press 'Enter' so the OK button is pressed. I mean I would like the OK button to be pre-selected (highlighted) so you can use enter without having to click on it.

I hope I'm clear enough. 
Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `button.focus()` to "pre-select" the button:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        dismiss = tk.Button(master, text = 'dismiss', command = self.on_dismiss)
        ok = tk.Button(master, text = 'ok', command = self.on_ok)
        ok.bind('<Return>', self.on_ok)
        dismiss.bind('<Escape>', self.on_dismiss) 
        ok.focus()
        dismiss.pack(fill = tk.BOTH)
        ok.pack(fill = tk.BOTH)
    def on_ok(self, event = None):
        print("Aww, it's okay!")
    def on_dismiss(self, event = None):
        print("Dismissed!")
root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Or, if you want the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to call `self.on_ok` globally, change `ok.bind` to `master.bind`.